# How to create an excel file at user given location in python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

*Actually the path and name will be given by two user defined variable(string) while creating an excel*
I tried with below logic but the excel file didn't get generated at that folder location.

```
Input_Output_Save_Folder_location = str(QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(Input_Output_Save_Folder_location +"/"+Excel_name+".xlsx")
```

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: Error is not coming. @Matthias

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

directory = "/my/happy/fun/directory"
filename = Excel_name + ".xlsx"

# optional: make sure the directory exists
if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```

Comment: I don't want to change my directory. @AKX

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you @AKX i came to know the issue.